# what is the meaning of "but lexophile that I was?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read this in "Word by Word" by Kory Samper:

> **But lexophile that I was**, I never considered spending a career on words.  I was a practical blue-collar girl.

What is the meaning of highlighted part? Does it mean same as "I was just a lexophile"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

idiomatic expression in English.

This type of inversion is used with expressing the idea that someone or something is emphatically something. It is used in writing more than in speech.

But lexophile **that I was** =**I was very much a** lexophile but [etc.]

It is very common in literary writing.

**Fool that he was**, he jumped out of a two-story building.

It can also mean because. Because he was a fool, he jumped out of a two-story building.

lexophile is a lover of words...